# Python Regex to extract last name with suffixes Jr. and Sr

Tags: python, regex

```py
LastName = re.sub(r"(,.)?(M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))$", "", Tbl['Full Name'][0]).strip().split(' ')[-1]
```

In Python, this regex works perfectly at extracting last names from full names except where the last name is followed by a suffix of "Jr." or "Sr."

An example name that is triggering a problem is `Ronald N. McDonald, Jr.`

What is solution to fix regex so that last names are extracted even with suffixes of Jr. and Sr.?

Comment: Does it really, though? What's an example of an actual value where this works? (e.g. what is in `Tbl['Full Name'][0]` when things work?) And why so specific, compared to something more "obvious" like `(\S+)(\s+(\S+))*?\s+(\S+)` that you can trivially append with an optional pattern for jr/sr like `(\s[jJsS]r\.)?`?

Comment: Please add sample data for names covering all edge cases.

Comment: Mike, I don't understand regex very well and can't even read this. It was provided by someone else on StackOverflow. I don't even know how it works. Do you have a better solution? Can you please put it together in a single line of code all together?

Comment: If you don't understand how regex work, then don't use them (and instead spend some time learning how they work). There's nothing wrong with string splitting and working with that instead by checking if the last element in the list is "Jr." or "Sr." for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you only want to get the pure last name no matter what a full name is composed of, i.e., 'Jr.', 'Sr.' would be discarded.

## Code based on Assumption

**Function**

```py
import re

def extract_last_name(full_name: str) -> str:
    pattern = r"(?:,\s?(?:Jr\.|Sr\.|M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3}))|(?:\s(?:I{1,3}|I?V|VI{0,3})$))?$"

    last_name = re.sub(pattern, "", full_name).strip().split(' ')[-1]
    return last_name
```

**Test cases**

```py
import unittest
from name_extractor import extract_last_name

class TestNameExtractor(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_extract_last_name(self):
        test_cases = [
            ("Ronald N. McDonald, Jr.", "McDonald"),
            ("John Smith, Sr.", "Smith"),
            ("Jane Doe", "Doe"),
            ("Alice Johnson III", "Johnson"),
            ("John P. Kennedy, IV", "Kennedy"),
        ]

        for full_name, expected_last_name in test_cases:
            result = extract_last_name(full_name)
            self.assertEqual(result, expected_last_name, f"Failed for '{full_name}': Expected '{expected_last_name}', got '{result}'")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

## Regex Explanation

1. `(?:...)?`: This is a non-capturing group that is optional (due to the ? at the end). It is used to group elements without capturing the matched text.
2. `,\s?`: This matches an optional comma followed by an optional whitespace character. It is used to account for cases where the suffix is separated from the last name by a comma and/or a space, e.g. "John Smith, Jr." or "John Smith Jr.".
3. `(?:Jr\.|Sr\.)`: This is a non-capturing group that matches either "Jr." or "Sr.". It is used to handle the cases where the suffix is "Jr." or "Sr.".
4. `M{0,4}(?:CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(?:XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(?:IX|IV|V?I{0,3})`: This part of the pattern matches Roman numerals. It is used to handle cases where the suffix is a Roman numeral.
5. `|(?:\s(?:I{1,3}|I?V|VI{0,3})$)`: This is an alternative part of the pattern, separated by `|`, which matches an optional space followed by a Roman numeral at the end of the string. This handles cases where the suffix is a Roman numeral but without a comma separating it from the last name.